# Number of homomorphisms from one group to another of the same order: G to Z_4

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have $(G,*)$ where $G=\{a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ and $*:a_i*a_j = a_{(i+j)(mod4)}$

I already showed this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_4}$ Now I need to find all homomorphisms from $G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_4}$

Since they are isomorphic, both of order 4 then can I use $\phi : \mathbb{Z_m} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_n}$ to say the number of homomorphisms is $gcd(m,n)$

which in this case would be $gcd(4,4)=4$.But, I am only coming up with the one 
homomorphism 
$\psi: G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_4}$,
$\psi(a_i) = i (mod 4)$

$\psi(a_i*a_j)=i +_4 j = \psi(a_i) +_4 \psi(a_j)$

***EDIT:*** oh wait I think I get it.
$\psi(a_1) =1, \psi(a_0) = 0, \psi(a_2) = 2, \psi(a_3) = 3$ so yeah 4

Comment: Still working on this one. so yeah there is four homomorphisms that can be made. like the one I did or another could be $(a_1) \mapsto 0$ where $\zeta(a_i) = i-1$  and the isomorphisms would be G rearranged in the cayley table which can be done 3 ways because $\mathbb{Z_4}$ has 3 possible configurations up to isomorphisms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$. This is because any such homomorphism is completely determined by where $G$ sends $a_1$. Ie, if $\varphi$ sends $a_1\mapsto 2\in\mathbb{Z}_4$, then $\varphi(a_2) = \varphi(a_1 * a_1) = \varphi(a_1) + \varphi(a_1) = 2 + 2 \equiv0\mod 4$, and so on.

Thus we have a bijection between homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ with the set of possible images of $a_1$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_4$ has size 4, you can send $a_1$ to any one of the 4 elements, so there are exactly 4 homomorphisms.

Comment: so the 4 homomorphisms are each element in G mapping to each element in $\mathbb{Z_4}$?

Comment: Okay suppose a homomorphism $\phi$ maps $a_1$ to 0, then $\phi(a_2) = \phi(a_1*a_1) = \phi(a_1) + \phi(a_1) = 0 + 0 = 0$, and $\phi(a_3) = \phi(a_2*a_1) = \phi(a_2) + \phi(a_1) = 0 + 0 = 0$, and similarly with $\phi(a_4) = \phi(a_3*a_1) = \phi(a_3) + \phi(a_1) = 0 + 0 = 0$.

Comment: Now suppose $\phi$ maps $a_1$ to 1, then $\phi(a_2) = \phi(a_1*a_1) = \phi(a_1) + \phi(a_1) = 1 + 1 = 2$, and $\phi(a_3) = \phi(a_2*a_1) = \phi(a_2) + \phi(a_1) = 2 + 1 = 3$, and $\phi(a_4) = \phi(a_3*a_1) = \phi(a_3) + \phi(a_1) = 3 + 1 = 4\equiv 0\mod 4$.

Comment: Now suppose $\phi$ maps $a_1$ to 2, then $\phi(a_2) = \phi(a_1*a_1) = \phi(a_1) + \phi(a_1) = 2 + 2 \equiv 0\mod 4$. Similarly, $\phi(a_3) = \phi(a_2*a_1) = \phi(a_2) + \phi(a_1) = 0 + 2 = 2$, and $\phi(a_4) = \phi(a_3*a_1) = \phi(a_3) + \phi(a_1) = 2 + 2 \equiv 0\mod 4$.

Comment: Lastly suppose $\phi$ maps $a_1$ to 3, then $\phi(a_2) = \phi(a_1*a_1) = \phi(a_1) + \phi(a_1) = 3 + 3 = 6 \equiv 2\mod 4$. Similarly, $\phi(a_3) = \phi(a_2*a_1) = \phi(a_2) + \phi(a_1) = 2 + 3 = 5 \equiv 1\mod 4$, and $\phi(a_4) = \phi(a_3*a_1) = \phi(a_3) + \phi(a_1) = 1 + 3\equiv 0\mod 4$.

Comment: In short, the four homomorphisms send $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ to $(0,0,0,0)$, $(1,2,3,0)$, $(2,0,2,0)$, or $(3,2,1,0)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$. In each case, the images of $a_2,a_3,a_4$ are all determined by the image of $a_1$, as shown in the comments above. (remember that a homomorphism isn't just any function. It must respect the group operations)